# Automate concatenate and If excel formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I am trying to automate this formula on excel vba using coding.

```
Dim ws Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet2

Dim frow 
frow = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

ws.Range(“W2:W” & frow).FormulaR1C1 =concatenate(IF(ISBLANK(W2), “”,W2&CHAR(10)),IF(ISBLANK(X2),””,X2&CHAR(10)),IF(ISBLANK(Y2), “”,Y2&CHAR(10)),IF(ISBLANK(Z2),””,Z2&CHAR(10)))
```

The formula works currently but the problem is there will be additional columns and I am not sure how to change the formula so that it would capture the first column in the formula to the last column in the formula, Is there another way to automate this formula in excel vba?

```
Dim ws Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet2

Dim frow 
frow = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

ws.Range(“W2:W” & frow).FormulaR1C1 =concatenate(IF(ISBLANK(W2), “”,W2&CHAR(10)),IF(ISBLANK(X2),””,X2&CHAR(10)),IF(ISBLANK(Y2), “”,Y2&CHAR(10)),IF(ISBLANK(Z2),””,Z2&CHAR(10)))
```

The formula works currently but the problem is there will be additional columns and I am not sure how to change the formula so that it would capture the first column in the formula to the last column in the formula, Is there another way to automate this formula in excel vba?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet2

Dim frow As Long
frow = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim formula As String
formula = ""

For i = 1 To Sheet2.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    formula = formula & ",IF(ISBLANK(RC" & i & "), """", RC" & i & "&CHAR(10))"
Next i

formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & Mid(formula, 2) & ")"

ws.Range("W2:W" & frow).FormulaR1C1 = formula
```

Comment: You should explain a little bit why this answer solves the problem